# Generated moles type for a static internal class is not accessible in test class

Tags: moles

I am trying to get access to an internal static class to override some of its methods so that I can test classes that depend on that class

From what I read that should be possible but I am not obviously not understanding everything as even a simple example seems to fail to generate a mole type for the internal static class.

I have two classes in a namespace and assembly

```
namespace SimpleClassToTest
{
    public class Class1
    {
        public string SayOla() { return Class2.ReturnMe("Ola"); }
    }
}


namespace SimpleClassToTest
{
    internal static class Class2
    {
        static public string ReturnMe(string m)
        {
            return m;
        }
    }
}
```

In AssemblyInfo.cs I also have

```
[assembly: InternalsVisibleTo("SimpleClassToTest")]
[assembly: InternalsVisibleTo("SimpleClassToTest.Moles")]
```

In the test project I have a single test class

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;

using SimpleClassToTest;
using SimpleClassToTest.Moles;

namespace SimpleClassToTest.Moles
{
    [TestClass]
    public class UnitTest1
    {
        public UnitTest1()
        {
        }

        [TestMethod]
        [HostType("Moles")]
        public void TestMethod1()
        {
            Class1 c1 = new Class1();
            Assert.AreEqual(c1.SayOla(), "Ola");
            MClass2.ReturnMeString = (ignored) => { return "ReturnMe"; };
            Assert.AreEqual(c1.SayOla(), "ReturnMe");
        }
    }
}
```

Unfortunately that is not compiling. The error is

> UnitTest1.cs(25,13): error CS0122: 'SimpleClassToTest.Moles.MClass2' is inaccessible due to its protection level

Any tips to get this going would certainly be appreciated!

Thanks!

Peter

PS Tried this both on VS2008 and on VS2010 with moles version Microsoft Moles v0.94.51023.0

**(Edit : From Comment Below)**

As a workaround, in the unit test:

```
Type mClass2Type = typeof(SimpleClassToTest.Moles.MClass1)
                    .Assembly.GetType("SimpleClassToTest.Mole‌​s.MClass2"); 
PropertyInfo returnMeProp = mClass2Type.GetProperty("ReturnMeString");
Microsoft.Moles.Framework.MolesDelegates.Func<String, String> molesDelegate = 
      (ignore) => { return "ReturnMe"; };
returnMeProp.SetValue(mClass2Type, molesDelegate, null);
Assert.AreEqual(c1.SayOla(), "ReturnMe");
```

Comment: As a workaround, in the unit test `Type mClass2Type = typeof(SimpleClassToTest.Moles.MClass1).Assembly.GetType("SimpleClassToTest.Moles.MClass2"); PropertyInfo returnMeProp = mClass2Type.GetProperty("ReturnMeString"); Microsoft.Moles.Framework.MolesDelegates.Func<String, String> molesDelegate = (ignore) => { return "ReturnMe"; }; returnMeProp.SetValue(mClass2Type, molesDelegate, null); Assert.AreEqual(c1.SayOla(), "ReturnMe"); } `

Answer (score 0):

If your assembly under test is strongly signed, then the moles assembly is also strongly signed, and you must specify the public key in the `InternalsVisibleTo` attribute. See the section "Code Generation and Compilation" of the moles reference manual for details.

Here is a quote that might be relevant:

> ... use this snippet as a
>   starting point to add **InternalsVisibleTo** attribute to your project.
>
> [assembly: InternalsVisibleTo(“FileSystem.Moles, PublicKey=0024000004800000940000000602000000240000525341310004000001000100e92decb949446f688ab9f6973436c535bf50acd1fd580495aae3f875aa4e4f663ca77908c63b7f0996977cb98fcfdb35e05aa2c842002703cad835473caac5ef14107e3a7fae01120a96558785f48319f66daabc862872b2c53f5ac11fa335c0165e202b4c011334c7bc8f4c4e570cf255190f4e3e2cbc9137ca57cb687947bc”)]

Comment: Don't think that is the problem. Certainly not in this little repro. That assembly is not signed